# suhosin encryption bug when reloading apache2 configuration

Tags: php, zend-framework, apache2, suhosin

I have a Apache2 server installed running with php and suhosin. The php session are handled with Zend_Session and stored in database. Suhosin is configured to encrypt session data before saving it to the database.

While apache2 is running after a

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

everything work fine until I ask apache2 to reload using

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

It seems that suhosin is not loaded correctly, and does not handle session data encryption anymore.

eg:

-before reload

```
mz0NTT8tcqaa4BIuBniVnVCMNjiwllLIds-cPt3KcMvyOHTktQmuYjgfAM3UMbVkVbsKnioUxPwjqaDIORSRlDnL5Q-W6iS8AoilOPwDUuUdtYjkbKskJpv62R9q
```

-after reload

```
language|a:2:{s:10:"locale";s:5:"en_EN";s:12:"language";s:2:"en";}
```

if apache is restarted sessions data are crypted again.

Here are the versions og the OS, apache2, php and suhosin I have:

```
squeeze/sid

Server version: Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Feb 22 2011 18:33:02

PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May  2 2011 23:18:30) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans
with Suhosin v0.9.32.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH
```

Does anyone have faced the same issue?
Any help on this would be very appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Finally found the solution. My apache was configured with suhosin and Xdebug. It seems that desactivating Xdebug allow suhosin to reload correctly while reloading apache.